# use Json auto into open Json in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, open-json

Is this syntax possible in SQL:

```
     SELECT * 
     FROM OPENJSON(SELECT * FROM FoodSara_tbl FOR JSON AUTO)
```

If yes, can you explain me how and why?

If no, Why? and what is the beast way instead of that?

Comment: I think double parenthesis should work `( ( SELECT...` although why you would ever do this I don't know.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this statement?

Comment: I wanted to open my Json table into the original one!

Comment: @SaraMoradi Then you need to use `OPENJSON` with explicit schema (the [WITH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#with_clause) clause).

Comment: yeah I used that in my original code, but I didn't want to mention that

Answer (score 0):

this query work correct !!!

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[temp1] FOR JSON AUTO)))
```

OPENJSON command give a string contain a json data as parameter
but when you generate json from table you have a pure json as result Set
and OPENJSON give a string parameter as json.

The two are different

if you  run this code

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[temp1] FOR JSON AUTO
```

you see this result

```
[{"Pname":"Ava","Pregion":"German","Pcount":10},{"Pname":"Ava","Pregion":"UK","Pcount":5}]
```

if put this result on OPENJSON

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON([{"Pname":"Ava","Pregion":"German","Pcount":10},{"Pname":"Ava","Pregion":"UK","Pcount":5}])
```

see below error

```
Invalid column name '{"Pname":"Ava","Pregion":"German","Pcount":10},{"Pname":"Ava","Pregion":"UK","Pcount":5}'.
```

but if you add  `'` at the first and foremost of your json. its parse correct

`'` is sign of string in SQL Server